# Ubuntu can't find WiFi on Mac

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't get any wifi to show up and I can't install a driver because I don't have a ethernet port so what do I do to get the WiFi to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package without an internet connection.

The `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `dkms` package and there required dependencies are on the livecd or liveusb disk that you installed ubuntu from.

Insert the livecd or liveusb disk, do not boot from the live disk then navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and copy and paste the bcmwl deb package to your desktop.

Now do the same with pool > main > d > dkms.

Now install the deb files. Open the terminal with CTRL+ALT+_T and:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: when i enter modprobe wl it says module wl not found

Comment: nevermind i got it

Comment: What was wrong?

Comment: i didn't install both packages

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to get the wifi to work on kali linux

Comment: Kali is off topic hear so we can not try to get it working, but I have never seen Kali but I believe it is an off shoot of ubuntu.

Comment: kali is fedora/red hat based, or at least I think it uses rpm/yum for packages/package manager, backtrack was debian kali is red hat/fedora

Comment: From this link it appears Kali is based on Debian still. http://docs.kali.org/category/introduction

Comment: hey sbergeron i tried entering sudo apt-get install yum on kali but it didnt enable the wifi do you have any other ideas on what to do